# How to Submit Form using JQuery with Multiple Submit Buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to make a Form in which there are two Submit buttons. Here is the form.

```
<form method="POST" id="addCreditsForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m10 offset-m1 l10 offset-l1 input-field">
            <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" required/>
            <label for="amount">Amount</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12">
            <p id="addWithPaypal" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" class="btn blue">Pay with Paypal</p>
            <p id="addWithInstamojo" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" class="btn blue">Pay with Instamojo</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am trying to do this with **JQuery**. Here is the JQuery Code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addWithPaypal").click(function(){
        $("#addCreditsForm").attr('action'."paypal/add/credits");
        $("#addCreditsForm").submit();
    });

    $("#addWithInstamojo").click(function(){
        $("#addCreditsForm").attr('action'."instamojo/add/credits");
        $("#addCreditsForm").submit();
    });
});
```

But When I click on any of the elements responsible for calling JQuery functions on Event, JQuery is not working. I tried to fire Alert on click event of both the buttons but it's not working too!
I have no Idea what's wrong. Please Help me out!

Answer (score 1):

Typo instead of `,` you kept `.` in

```
`$("#addCreditsForm").attr('action',"instamojo/add/credits");`
                                       ^here  

$("#addCreditsForm").attr('action',"paypal/add/credits");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addWithPaypal").click(function(){
        $("#addCreditsForm").attr('action',"paypal/add/credits");
        $("#addCreditsForm").submit();
    });

    $("#addWithInstamojo").click(function(){
        $("#addCreditsForm").attr('action',"instamojo/add/credits");
        $("#addCreditsForm").submit();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="addCreditsForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m10 offset-m1 l10 offset-l1 input-field">
            <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" required/>
            <label for="amount">Amount</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12">
            <p id="addWithPaypal" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" class="btn blue">Pay with Paypal</p>
            <p id="addWithInstamojo" style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;" class="btn blue">Pay with Instamojo</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, That's the solution! How can I be so dumb, Lol!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you @AdarshSojitra